# Ubuntu 16.04.2 shutdown wait for 10 minutes after the step 'Stopped LVM2 metadata daemon'

Tags: shutdown

I installed Ubuntu 16.04.2 from ubuntu-16.04.2-server-amd64.iso. It was working fine. But once I deployed all the patches, it started waiting for ten minutes after the step "Stopped LVM2 metadata daemon" during shutdown.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem a couple of days ago.
What I did to work out this issue was quite simple. Just edit the /usr/share/unattended-upgrades/unattended-upgrade-shutdown file at the line 120 this way:

Before: if apt_pkg.config.find_b("Unattended-Upgrade::InstallOnShutdown", False)

After: if apt_pkg.config.find_b("Unattended-Upgrade::InstallOnShutdown", false)

I hope it works for you too.